# AWS health checker is active, but no load balancer has been configured

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have just configured a site on an EC2 instance on Amazon, with running Apache and PHP. Everything works fine. However, I've noticed the log keep getting filled with 404 messages trying to access `/_hostmanager/healthcheck`.

My research tells me that this is related to Amazons elastic load balancer, doing an automatic health check each x minutes. The user agent seems to indicate this as well: `ELB-HealthChecker/1.0`.

However, I have not configured any load balancer in any region. I have not been able to find any other causes than this being related to the load balancer, so this does not make any sense to me.

Any ideas or experiences with this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Elastic Beanstalk?

Local instance management is performed by Amazons HostManager. HostManager is a Ruby application based on Rack and running in a Thin server on port 8999. It receives requests on URI /_hostmanager.

http://blog.jetztgrad.net/2011/01/dissecting-an-amazon-elastic-beanstalk-instance/

Comment: If I select Beanstalk: "You do not have any AWS Elastic Beanstalk applications launched". So I guess the answer is no.